# Openfire VOIP Client, How To Use Media Proxy

Tags: java, openfire

I recently developed an VOIP app on android device. But it lacks of acrossing wlan capability. One UDP connection was established between two client phone in the same lan. The two phone client was communicated via its ipv4 address directly. But now I'm wandering that how could they talk to each other over the wlan? They maybe stay behind the firewall. I was talked that Openfire has the Media Proxy functionality which could be the agent to transfer data. But I cannot find any example of this feature. Could you please give me any advice? Thanks very much. Sincerely.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have implemented a Jingle client. In order to make this work you should make sure that:

- Openfire (acting as a Media Proxy as well) is running on a computer with a
  public IP, so that each client behind any NAT can "talk" to it
- Your client media engine does support [symmetric RTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4961)

To enable Media Proxy in Openfire is simple as going to Openfire server web console (usually at openfirehost:9090/index.jsp), select tab "Media Services", set the option "Enabled" at "Media Proxy Settings" and then click on "Save Settings".

PS: My Openfire version is 3.9.1